# Debug javascript from ASP.NET in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, webforms

I want to be able to debug the client-side Javascript generated by WebForms for, say, a button click.

This should be trivial, but I can't find a simple way to do it.

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Content$btnUpdate" value="Save" 
    id="ctl00_Content_btnUpdate" class="StandardButton"
    onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
                    "ctl00$Content$btnUpdate", "", true, "", "", false, false))" 
    >
```

...and it's generated from this `.aspx` snippet:

```
<AGILE:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="StandardButton" Text="@Save@"
                    OnClick="btnUpdate_Click"/>
```

What's the fastest way to attach a debugger to the function `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(...)` in Visual Studio (2013 FWIW)?

What about in Chrome Dev Tools?

#### What I've tried:

(see my answer below)

Comment: this can help-->http://stackoverflow.com/a/15568279/823161

Answer (score 1):

#### For Chrome Dev Tools:

1. `Ctrl-Shift-C` to get in 'find-me-this-DOM-element` mode and click the button.
2. In the Dev tools, look at what the `onclick` event points to (see example in the question), copy the function name.
3. `Ctrl-Shift-F` for 'find-me-everything-everywhere' mode, and paste the function name (aka `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions`). `<Enter>`.
4. Set breakpoint in Chrome Dev tools and go from there.

#### For Visual Studio

I figured out (from the above steps for Chrome) that the generated javascript lives in a file named `WebResource.axd?d=<random>` that's generated when the page is accessed.

#### Update

When using Internet Explorer as the client browser, there's better integration with Visual Studio.

In VS pre-2012, [there was, apparently, a *Script Editor* window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385621%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under Debug -> Windows (available only when debugging, while attached to IE).

In VS 2012/2013, this was replaced by a node named *Script Documents* in the Solution Explorer window. This follows the page currently open in the br

[image]

It only appears while debugging with IE as the selected browser.

[image]

Armed with the knowledge from the Chrome steps above, I opened the `WebResource.axd` file and sure enough, my function was the first one in the file. I could just add a breakpoint and move on.

[image]

However, I couldn't find a way to *search* for that function from Visual Studio.

---

The methods I described get the job done, but I still hope there's an easier way...