# Debug third party Javascript with Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

I need to debug Javascript from external sources. I found out that you can use either Firefox or Chrome to debug scripts with the internal JS debugger. But the features in these browser developer tools are limited and not the same like in a good IDE. For example I cannot create conditions for breakpoints or setting the command pointer to any other line of code. So my question is how could I use Visual Studio or any other comfortable IDE to do this? I started by opening a new web application in VS and tried to download all the scripts locally. This will work till it comes to special parameters which are not the same like it would run in the real browser e.g. window.location.href

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code with [Debugger for Chrome extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code) can help you debug Javascript in Visual Studio Code IDE.

Please install [Visual Studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and install Debugger for Chrome extension based on this document:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_browse-and-install-extensions

Now you can open your project and start debugging your project. After launch in Chrome, you could add breakpoint through Debug menu -> New Breakpoint to choose which type of breakpoint you want to add.

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you very much. I can't mark the answer as the correct one yet.
I just wonder why it worked only once. Now it doesn't show me any "loaded scripted" in VS Code anymore. Anyway is this also possible with full VS or only in VS Code? Is there any extension which beautifies the JS like in the chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the keyword “debugger” to the line where you want to debug(in JS script files) and then run the Visual Studio in Debug mode by pressing F5.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29385418/9125096

**UPDATE:**
First, you need enable in JavaScript debugging... in the options of Debug:

[Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9AhO.png)

I wrote my JS code just like:

```
alert(1)
debugger;
alert(2)
```

[JS code in Temp.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo5SX.png)

and put it in html file as an external source:
[HTML FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRIXf.png)

Then I press F5, it shows me the first alert:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOitE.png)

I clicked OK, it stopped at the **debugger** location in Temp.js file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW9zY.png)